# Eventstore client for NodeJs(@eventstore/db-client) stops the execution when 'maxCount' for reading the events from stream is increased more than 20

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventstoredb

The program run fines when I have the following configuration:

```
let events = eventstoreClient.readStream(
       streamName,
       {
         fromRevision: END,
         direction: BACKWARDS,
         maxCount: 20
       }
     );
```

However, the program stucks(i.e. could not read the streams/events further) when maxCount is set to 100 or 1000 or maxCount option is not supplied!

Answer (score 6):

`readStream` returns a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readable-streams) which will buffer the events internally until they exceed the `highWaterMark` threshold. The data will sit in the internal queue until it is consumed, and the stream will temporarily stop reading events from the server until the data currently buffered has been consumed.

When you request 20 events they fit within internal buffer, so after 20 events the stream closes and NodeJS is happy to stop execution. However, if you request 100 or 1000 events, once the internal buffer is full, the stream won't be closed as there are still events to be read from the server, and it will wait for you to consume those events.

You need to pull the events from the buffer to allow the streaming read to finish. This can be done in a number of ways, for example:

Iterate through the steam:

```
for await (const { event } of events) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

or add an event listener:

```
events.on("data", (event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

You can read more about buffering here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#buffering

Comment: Thank you, I am using the first iteration approach to read events, but it get stuck even with that approach, but the problem is not there when there are only 20 events!

Comment: can you add the code that gets stuck to the question?

Comment: I ran into this same issue, but I ran into this issue by adding a `break` to my iteration once I read far enough into the stream, and running the operation multiple times. I think doing that left events on the buffer so that when successive operations read from EventStoreDB it would eventually stall once the buffer got full.